# The extra benefits of `multiprocessing` in a minimal demonstrating example

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am learning `multiprocessing` from "Introducing Python", there's such a example to demonstrate the `multiprocessing`

```
import os
import multiprocessing as mp

def do_this(what):
    whoami(what)

def whoami(what):
    print(f"Process {os.getpid()} says: {what}.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    whoami("I'm the main program.")
    for i in range(4):
        p = mp.Process(target=do_this, args=(f"I'm function {i}",))
        p.start()

def do_this(what):
    whoami(what)

def whoami(what):
    print(f"Process {os.getpid()} says: {what}.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    whoami("I'm the main program.")
    for i in range(4):
        do_this(f"I'm function {i}")
```

Run it and come by:

```
## -- End pasted text --
Process 2197 says: I'm the main program..
Process 2294 says: I'm function 1.
Process 2293 says: I'm function 0.
Process 2295 says: I'm function 2.
Process 2296 says: I'm function 3.
```

However, it's easily achieved by a single process:

```
def do_this(what):
    whoami(what)

def whoami(what):
    print(f"Process {os.getpid()} says: {what}.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    whoami("I'm the main program.")
    for i in range(4):
        do_this(f"I'm function {i}")
## -- End pasted text --
Process 2197 says: I'm the main program..
Process 2197 says: I'm function 0.
Process 2197 says: I'm function 1.
Process 2197 says: I'm function 2.
Process 2197 says: I'm function 3.
```

I try best to grasp the idea of `multiprocessing` and what's problem it solved if not introduced in.

In the above case, what's the extra benefits of `multiprocessing`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind [multiprocessing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiprocessing) is that you can take a problem that requires a lot of math to run, and split the workload between multiple computing systems.

This is often done within a single computer, but can also happen over a network of computers. In the case of python a "multi-process" is executed within a single computer.

The way this works is modern cpu's have several cores. Each core is like it's own processor, in that it can process a single thread at a time.

The reason cpu's are divided into cores is because it's hard to make a single core faster, but it's easy to add more cores, which in turn gives you more total processing power.

The problem with this is that each core can only execute a single thread at a time. So if your program is entirely single threaded it doesn't matter how many cores you have it will only run at the speed of the single core it's on.

Dividing your python script like you did above separates it into several threads that can run independently on different cores. Each core processes the task you give it and the final answer is combined and printed to the screen.

In your example there really is no beneficent to using multiprocessing because you aren't doing a significant amount of work to slow the program down, but say you had massive arrays that required expensive math to run, dividing that array into parts and distributing those parts to the different processes would make the overall program run faster.

Comment: A couple of things to note: In general, multiprocessing isn't just on one computer but can be across many (aka a "cluster"), but Python's `multiprocessing` module only runs on one computer. Python also has `Thread`s that are different than the threads of the OS. Multiple Python `Thread`s actually run on one OS-level thread. Python's `multiprocessing` module uses separate processes to allow multiple cores to be used, but they can't share memory like multiple threads of one process would be able to, a simplification.

Comment: @sudo thank you and excellent points. I edited my answer to reflect what you wrote.